# Why does the replacement pattern "**$&" on input string "$1.30" returns a string with "**" before and "after" the input string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#substitutions), the `"$&"` substitution character sequence returns a copy of the whole match. I cannot wrap my head around why in the replaced string with the pattern `"(\$*(\d*(\.+\d+)?){1})"` with replacement string `"**$&"` on input string `"$1.30"` there is a trailing `"**"`. The result string is `"**$1.30**"`

EDIT: perhaps, coming back to this at a later time would give me the answer (as is the case with most regex problems :P), but I'd like to sleep tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the code that the MSDN article suggests:

```
Regex.Replace("$1.30", @"(\$*(\d*(\.+\d+)?){1})", "**$0") // **$1.30**
```

Now look closely at the pattern. Technically, an empty string matches the pattern, for example:

```
Regex.Replace("", @"(\$*(\d*(\.+\d+)?){1})", "**$0") // **
```

As a consequence, the zero-length sub-string that appears after the first match (`$1.30`) also matches the pattern. So there are two replacements made in the original case, one that results in `**$1.30` and one that results in `**`. This can be confirmed if you try the substitution pattern `($&)`:

```
Regex.Replace("$1.30", @"(\$*(\d*(\.+\d+)?){1})", "($&)") // ($1.30)()
```

Comment: Legend! Totally get it now. Thanks. Now since you've used `$0` in your example, I wonder what the difference between `$0` and `$&` is.

Comment: @Abhinav There's no difference, AFAIK. They just two different ways of referring to the same thing (just like `..*` is the same as `.+`)